# Post rating system in iOS with parse.com - upvote / downvote

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

**Simply**: I want rating system of the post (or image) that works the same as in Yik Yak or 9gag - **user can upvote or downvote only once the post**. I dont want to store these data on device but everything on parse.com. I also would like to **count the comments**. Ideally do everything in only one query to parse.com

I am using currently this code but I dont think this is the good approach how to do it because for every image it will create a new query. Currently I have 4 tables in Parse.com User, Image, Comment, Rating and everything is connected with pointers to the image or user.

```
func loadData(){
    forPaginationStart = 0
    numberOfImagesPerPage = 5
    imageData.removeAllObjects()
    var findImageData: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Image")
    findImageData.whereKey("deleted", equalTo: 0)
    findImageData.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    findImageData.skip = forPaginationStart
    findImageData.limit = numberOfImagesPerPage
    findImageData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects! {

                let image:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                self.imageData.addObject(image)

                //comment counts
                var countComments = PFQuery(className:"Comment_image")
                countComments.whereKey("image_id", equalTo: PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Image", objectId: "\(image.objectId!)"))
                countComments.whereKey("deleted", equalTo: 0)
                countComments.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        println("There is \(count) comments for image: \((object.objectId!)!)")
                        self.commentCount.append(countComments.countObjects())
                    }
                }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }

    //count number of records in DB for pagination end
    var totalNumOfRows: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Image")
    totalNumOfRows.whereKey("deleted", equalTo: 0)
    totalNumOfRows.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            self.totalNumRecords = Int(count)
            println("total records: \(self.totalNumRecords)")
        }


    }
}
```

I had it working with php and SQL but with parse the same approach doesnt work for me... I asked the DB what is the value for that user, if it was 1 the user upvoted and if negative one he downvoted, 0 neither one and I set the button according to the value
SQL query:

```
IFNULL((SELECT value FROM rating WHERE image.id = rating.image_id AND rating.user_id = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE uuid='$uuid')), 0) as UserRating
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (instancetype)whereKey:(NSString *)key matchesKey:(NSString *)otherKey inQuery:(PFQuery *)query
```

You can use [this method on PFQuery](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:matchesKey:inQuery:), for example:

```
var countComments = PFQuery(className:"Comment_image")
var findImageData: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Image")
findImageData.whereKey("deleted", equalTo: 0)
findImageData.orderByDescending("createdAt")
findImageData.skip = forPaginationStart
findImageData.limit = numberOfImagesPerPage
countComments.whereKey("image_id", matchesKey:"objectId", inQuery: )
countComments.whereKey("deleted", equalTo: 0)
countComments.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (count: Int32, error: NSError?) -> Void in
     if error == nil {
         println("There is \(count) comments for all images!")
     }
}
```

By setting up the count query like this, you don't have to call count for each image, but I don't know in the background if Parse optimizes to make it faster than your current query.